# Can GWT co-exist with other libraries?

Tags: javascript, gwt, libraries

I have an application that uses GWT. GWT doesn't support my ability to upgrade my BI charts. Can GWT co-exist with other libraries so that I do not have to rip out all of GWT at once and I can continue to release versions of my software on a regular basis?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812164/how-to-include-3rd-party-javascript-libraries-in-a-reusable-gwt-library-widget

Answer (score 1):

Yes GWT co-exists with javascript libraries well.  Your java code can call javascript code in the library using JsInterop or the deprecated JSNI.

Generally you can also mix DOM elements generated by the javascipt library with GWT Widgets.